# How to write a Perl script to convert file to all upper case?

Tags: perl, file, uppercase

How can I write a Perl script to convert a text file to all upper case letters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
perl -ne "print uc" < input.txt
```

The `-n` wraps your command line script (which is supplied by `-e`) in a `while` loop. A `uc` returns the ALL-UPPERCASE version of the default variable `$_`, and what `print` does, well, you know it yourself. ;-)

The `-p` is just like `-n`, but it does a `print` in addition. Again, acting on the default variable `$_`.

To store that in a script file:

```
#!perl -n
print uc;
```

Call it like this:

```
perl uc.pl < in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: add `-C` for utf-8 files e.g., `echo aßbc | perl -C -ne'print uc'` -> `ASSBC`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  This worked for me.  The info was useful and I modified it to output to a file, which was simple.  For other novices, you have to put double quotes around directory and filename if it is not in current directory.

Comment: Just one more followup question... How can I write this and store it in a Perl file?  So that I just give it input file and output file arguments?

Comment: #!perl -n
print uc;

In two lines! Then call it like this:

perl uc.pl < in.txt > out.txt

Comment: I tried that but it didn't do anything.  How do I add input/output info to the command prompt when I run this Perl script?  Also, this script doesn't look long enough

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -pe '$_= uc($_)' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I tried this but I modified it slightly with the directory information.  However, this gives me the error: "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1"

Answer (score 2):

> perl -pe '$_ = uc($_)' input.txt > output.txt

But then you don't even need Perl if you're using Linux (or *nix). Some other ways are:

awk:

> awk '{ print toupper($0) }' input.txt >output.txt

tr:

> tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < input.txt > output.txt

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't use Linux though.

Comment: Ok, np. Eventhough Perl is of much help to Linux users, I always thought it's help is much more for Windows users; just because of the fact that Linux is so rich with tools that one task can be done through many of its standard utilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -Tpe " $_ = uc; " --

$ perl -MO=Deparse -Tpe " $_ = uc; " -- a s d f
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    $_ = uc $_;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK

$ cat myprogram.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -T --
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    $_ = uc $_;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```